# Can't style a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am applying style qualities to a div containing external javascript, and they seem to be ignored by the browser.  The first div works correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/TxWN3/2/

```
<div style="text-align:center;">Working center text</div>

<div id="btc-quote" style="text-align:center;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="//cdn-gh.firebase.com/btcquote/embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: Specifically what's being ignored? Your fiddle links to a rather large JS file so it's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: The second div is not being centered while the firs div is.

Comment: You aren't using the right CSS for that. You can't center the div inside that div with `text-align: center;`

Comment: Are you referring to the `text-align:center;`? If so I believe you have gotten confused about what the does. The `width` of the first div is actually the width of the current page. The problem is coming from you specifying the width of the second div. To see width of the first div see here : http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/TxWN3/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center it, first give it a width and then margin:0 auto:

```
<div id="btc-quote" style="width:212px;margin:0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The content of the div class="btc-quote" might have some css code not wanting it to center. (I have not read all that code from BTC) To workaround this, you can make the div itself centering, not the content.

A simple trick to do this is add the following css to the div:

```
width:212px;
margin:auto;
```

This is a nice workaround found [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)

Answer (score 1):

To center your included div, add this CSS:

```
.btc-box {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TxWN3/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

The [`text-align:center;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) CSS property is not used in the way you are assuming.

If you check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/TxWN3/5), you will see that the default width of a div is the width of the container, and so when you center the text it appears the div is centered. However this is not the case.

To center a Div you can use the [`Position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) CSS property :

Add the following CSS attributes :

```
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-106px; /* Half of the width of the div */
```

And see the following fiddle for the Second Div being center aligned

http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/TxWN3/7/